# install ubuntu in a file on windows partition (similar to Wubi installer)

Tags: boot, windows, wubi

I am installing ubuntu in a file on my ntfs windows partition.

This is quite easy to do:

```
disable safe boot in bios
you might also need to set AHCI SSD interface access
boot and run live cd
```

open a terminal and as root

```
#mount ntfs partition
mount -t ntfs /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt
#create installation folder
mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
#create virtual drive
mknod /dev/sdx b 7 100
#create virtual disk image
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ubuntu/ubuntu.img bs=1G count=256
#link the virtual drive to the virtual disk image
losetup /dev/sdx /mnt/ubuntu/ubuntu.img
```

and install ubuntu in /dev/sdx like on a separate disk.

common problems:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3 not showing up - these are related to bios settings
mount -t ntfs /dev/nvme0n1p3 /host fail to mount - windows partition can be encrypted, so disable from windows (no need to format or reinstall windows)
```

to boot from the new environment I use grub config:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'ubuntu' {
        rmmod tpm
        loopback loop (hd0,gpt3)/ubuntu/ubuntu.img
        root=(loop)
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-generic root=/dev/sdx rw verbose nosplash
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-generic
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
```

the rmmod tpm is causing mounting loop to hang (grub 2.04)

on older versions loading ntfs driver was needed (grub 2.02):
modprobe ntfs

this will actually drop the boot process to initramfs shell

at this point you need to manually add commands to load the image

```
#create mount point needed by initramfs image
mkdir /host
#mount ntfs partition
mount -t ntfs /dev/nvme0n1p3 /host
#create virtual drive
mknod /dev/sdx b 7 100
#link the virtual drive to the virtual disk image
losetup /dev/sdx /host/ubuntu/ubuntu.img
#continue boot up
exit
```

this can be easily added to an initramfs scripts.

my question is, can we add this functionality to Ubuntu?

I find it easy to do and very useful. I can boot ubuntu in a native environment, but also can move my image around just like a virtual disk image.
To move my installation, I just need to follow the same steps on another instance, and just copy my ubuntu.img file from the old instance and overwrite it on the new instance.

Thank you,
Razvan

Comment: So what is the question? What fo you mean by "can we add this functionality to Ubuntu?" Who are we? You can add anything you like.

Comment: This is a request for a new feature, which is off-topic on AskUbuntu

Comment: have opened a feature request on https://discourse.ubuntu.com/. anyway, if anybody wants to try this and give some feedback, or if this is of any help to anybody, I am going to leave this description here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may open a feature request at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu and it should be looked at in 24 hours.